# undefined reference to symbol '_ZTIPKc@@CXXABI_1.3' when running opencv c++ file in raspberry pi 3

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm new to c++ and raspberry pi. And I just installed opencv in my raspberry pi, trying to run some simple code to test it. However, when I try to read a image using opencv in cpp, error occurs like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc72shlb.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZTIPKc@@CXXABI_1.3'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My cpp code is:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Mat img = imread("/home/pi/c_programming/download.jpeg");
    imshow("image", img);
    return 0;
}
```

While my command is:

```
gcc mytest.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

I think the opencv works in my raspberry pi because I've tested it using the example by

```
./opencv_example
```

Can someone tells me how to correct this code please? Thank you.

Comment: Add `stdc++` library to your linker input

Comment: Best to compile C++ with: `g++`

Comment: Which version of OpenCV? Version 2 as in your `#include` path, or version 4 as in your `pkg-cfg` command?